# Is there a way to make a checkpoint system in batch files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to make a checkpoint system in batch files? I'm teaching myself batch, and creating a text-based RPG type game, but if the program is closed, it starts back at the very beginning of the code, with no progress saved. I want to make a complex long term game, but I don't want to have to deal with a restart of the game every time. Is there a way to save progress so you can re-open the program and either restart OR resume where you left off, with all previous choices intact?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest save/reload method is this:

Reserve a character (say, `#`) to be used as the first character of all of the variables you want to record.

so...

```
set #points=35
set action=3
set #money=22
```

To save all of the `#` variables, use

```
set #>filename
```

which would save `#money` and `#points`, but not `action`

To reload use

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do set "%%a"
```

which will reload all of the variables saved in the file - which are, of course, only #variables.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to magoo's answer regarding a very efficient save / load method, (with a slight modification):
scripting user profiles can be done like so:

```bat
@Echo off
rem /* predefine your key variables prior to this loop */
:name :# load point
 Set /P "name=Enter your name: "
 If Not "%name%" == "" (
rem /* If character exists; load */
  If Exist "%~n0_%name%.bat" (
   Call "%~n0_%name%.bat"
rem /* Initialise character save using predefined variables if character new */
  ) Else ( Call :Save )
rem /* Force Assignment of name variable */
 ) Else ( Goto name )
===============================================
::: Script body
::: End of Script
Goto :Eof
===============================================
:Save :# function
rem /* variation on magoo's method of saving */
 (For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Set #')Do Echo/Set "%%G")>"%~n0_%name%.bat"
Exit /B 0
```